# Get dynamic and static IPv6 address

Tags: 16.04, ipv6, network-bonding, dynamic-ip, dhcpv6

I'm trying to make my Ubuntu 16.04.1 home server have (at least) two IPv6 addresses for its bonding interface of two physical network interfaces:

1. A static local one from the `fd::` range (for a Samba4 primary domain controller).
2. A dynamic global one, acquired automatically, or assigned by the router (an AVM FritzBox 6360 in my case, from by my cable TV provider Unitymedia).

Of course it should still have a static local IPv4 address.

It used to work no problem about a year ago when I set up a different box, but I'm currently unable to reproduce that.

The problem is that my box does not learn the router's subnet (something in the `20a2::` range), but only has the configured static and an `fe80::` address. How to change that? (Detail on my configuration below.)

I'm not intending to use network manager, but `/etc/network/interfaces`; here's what it currently looks like:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    mtu 4000

auto eno2
iface eno2 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    mtu 4000

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
    mtu 4000
    bond-mode 0
    bond-slaves none
iface bond0 inet6 static
    address fdde:beda:1706:5326:dc::1
    gateway fdde:beda:1706:5326:a96:d7ff:fe58:3781
    dns-nameservers fdde:beda:1706:5326:a96:d7ff:fe58:3781
    netmask 64
    accept_ra 1
    autoconf 1
    mtu 4000
    bond-mode 0
    bond-slaves none
```

I have installed `rdnssd` as it is mentioned in the the manpage for the above file in the inet6 section, but I have not changed its default configuration.
Here's the result of `ifconfig` after rebooting:

```
bond0 Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 0c:c4:7a:80:39:86  
      inet Adresse:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      inet6-Adresse: fe80::ec4:7aff:fe80:3986/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
      inet6-Adresse: fdde:beda:1706:5326:dc::1/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:4000  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:1195 Fehler:0 Verloren:4 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:837 Fehler:0 Verloren:15 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX-Bytes:134895 (134.8 KB)  TX-Bytes:120940 (120.9 KB)

eno1  Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 0c:c4:7a:80:39:86  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:4000  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:613 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:466 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX-Bytes:71702 (71.7 KB)  TX-Bytes:64530 (64.5 KB)
      Interrupt:16 Speicher:df300000-df320000 

eno2  Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 0c:c4:7a:80:39:86  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:4000  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:582 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:371 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX-Bytes:63193 (63.1 KB)  TX-Bytes:56410 (56.4 KB)
      Speicher:df100000-df17ffff 

lo    Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
      inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
      inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:172 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:172 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1 
      RX-Bytes:12560 (12.5 KB)  TX-Bytes:12560 (12.5 KB)
```

Sorry for the german content, but I guess that if you know `ifconfig`'s output, you can still get the relevant information.

My router is currently configured to just assign DNS name server's via DHCPv6, but can as well by configured to additionally assign a prefix (IA_PD), and furthermore an IPv6 address (IA_NA).
I've tested all three options - none of them had a recognizable effect.

Comment: I've just figured out that the `inet6`config seems to be ok - it works as soon as the `inet` (IPv4) config is set to `dhcp` instead of `static`. However, I want both (IPv4 and v6) addresses to be static...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can I say? The above configuration seems to be correct, it works now although I haven't changed anything...who said that computers were deterministic?